# Gradient color drawable not working properly on Android 10 (rotated 90 degrees)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I applied a **gradient drawable** resource as a background for a view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#cf2aff"
        android:endColor="#5409ff"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

In devices with `Android version < 10` it is shown as expected:

[image: gradient background 1]

But in devices with `Android 10` it is rotated 90 degrees:

[image: gradient background 2]

Did anyone have the same problem and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `android:angle="0"`

I got a fix for this. You need to set `android:angle` attribute even if it is 0 to make it work on **Android 10**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#cf2aff"
        android:endColor="#5409ff"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

I suppose for Android 10, angle is set to 90 degrees by default.

Answer (score 3):

Just an addition: I noticed that a negative angles get ignored on some devices. So always use positive numbers between 0 and 360 when setting the angle!

e.g.: instead of

```
android:angle="-45"
```

use

```
android:angle="315"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the angle to 180 degrees? Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:startColor="#cf2aff"
        android:endColor="#5409ff"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Set the angle to 180 will show gradient background reversed for all Android versions. But I realised if you set it to 0 it will show gradient correctly for Android 10 :)